# Rails: set a date field when an attribute changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app with categories 'Active', 'Waitlist', and 'Terminated'.  These are in the view as a select box.

When the user selects 'Terminated' I want to put the current date into a datetime attribute (in the same model).

What's the best way to do this?  I tried this, but it didn't work, and I'm not sure it's the right place to do it:

[in the controller]

```
def update
  @household = Household.find(params[:id])
  if @household.status.eql? 'Terminated'
      @household.terminated = Date.yesterday()
  end
  if @household.update_attributes(params[:household])
    ....
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use after_update callback in your model:

```
class Household
...
after_update :update_terminated_date

def update_terminated_date
    return unless status == 'Terminated'
    self.terminated = Date.today() # maybe better Time.now?
    self.save!
end
```

EDIT:
Maybe better idea is to just get rid of status column and set terminated to date when it's really terminated and to null when it's not?

Comment: That's nice!  It works.  Just curious though, doesn't the "self.save!" amount to 2 database writes, since the row was just updated (and written) by the controller?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you can change after_update to before_update and remove the save.